# Spring Data findTop10- Ten queries instead of one

Tags: java, sql, performance, spring-data

I have Spring Data method like this:

```
List<RegionBasics> findTop10ByRegionMappingsActiveTrue();
```

What I expect is that it will find top 10 records from db in one query but What I see in logs is (I didn't paste whole logs in order to keep this readable but this select query is invoke 10 times):

> select regionmapp0_.id as id1_2_1_, regionmapp0_.is_active as is_activ2_2_1_, regionmapp0_.region_basic_id as region_b3_2_1_, regionbasi1_.id as id1_1_0_, regionbasi1_.hotel_count as hotel_co2_1_0_, regionbasi1_.name_long as name_lon3_1_0_, regionbasi1_.name as name4_1_0_, regionbasi1_.type as type5_1_0_ from region_mappings regionmapp0_ left outer join region_basics regionbasi1_ on regionmapp0_.region_basic_id=regionbasi1_.id where regionmapp0_.region_basic_id=?

How can I ensure that this method will hit db only once (instead of 10)?

My Model:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "region_basics")
public class RegionBasics {

    @Id
    Integer id;

    @Column
    String type;

    @Column
    String name;

    @Column(name = "name_long")
    String longName;

    @Column(name = "hotel_count")
    Integer hotelCount;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="regionBasics")
    RegionMappings regionMappings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should join fetching the RegionMappings:
Like this: `@Query("SELECT rb FROM RegionBasics r JOIN FETCH r.regionMappings rm WHERE  rm.active=true")`
With pageable parameter `new PageRequest(0,10)`